# Simultaneous Inserts to Multiple Tables?

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

My project is using Dapper to connect to an Oracle database instance. In one critical section of code, we need to do a whole lot of data insertions. The tables are structured as follows:

```
* Table_Master
  - ID (PK)
  - ... Unrelated fields ...
* Table_A
  - ID (PK)
  - FK_Table_Master
  - ... Unrelated fields ...
* Table_B
  - Same structure as table A
```

Since the only links are `A --> Master` and `B --> Master`, I can insert data for tables A and B simultaneously as long as I have the key into the master table. Is it possible to do this within the same database context in Dapper? E.g., Can I simultaneously execute multiple

`context.Execute("INSERT INTO ...")`

In different threads? I will run up some tests to see if I run into anything out of the ordinary, but I'm wondering if anyone has tried this before and what results they achieved. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on sharing a context into multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can do insert into several tables using one `INSERT ALL` statement as

```
insert all 
  into tab_1 (col1, col2) values (1, 2)
  into tab_2 (col8, col3) values ('a', 'x')
  ...
select * from dual;
```

Comment: Good idea! I hadn't thought of that... Unfortunately it would require some significant refactoring to get all the inserts "cached" as I build the insert all command ... something for me to look into. Thanks!